# Create an array with tree elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, tree

I need to create an array from tree elements in Javascript and being a newbie I don't know how to achieve this.

pseudo-code :

```
function make_array_of_tree_node(tree_node)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < tree_node.childCount; i ++) {
      var node = tree_node_node.getChild(i);
      if (node.type ==0) {
         // Here I'd like to put a link (node.title) in an array as an element
      } else if (node.type ==6) {
         // Here the element is a folder so a I need to browse it
         make_array_of_tree_node(node)
      }
   }
}

// Some code
make_array_of_tree_node(rootNode);
// Here I'd like to have access to the array containing all the elements node.title
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is missing a close `}`.

Comment: @Mike Samuel A typo in SO, thank you for noticing it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an array like this:

```
var nodes = [];
```

Then you can add things to it with:

```
nodes.push(something);
```

That adds to the end of the array; in that sense it's kind-of like a list.  You can access elements by numeric indexes, starting with zero.  The length of the array is maintained for you:

```
var len = nodes.length;
```

What you'll probably want to do is make the array another parameter of your function.

*edit* — To illustrate the pattern, if you've got a recursive function:

```
function recursive(data, array) {
  if ( timeToStop ) {
    array.push( data.whatever );
  }
  else {
    recursive(data.subData, array);
  }
}
```

Then you can use a *second* function to be the real API that other code will use:

```
function actual(data) {
  var array = [];
  recursive(data, array); // fills up the array
  return array;
}
```

In JavaScript, furthermore, it's common to place the "recursive" function *inside* the "actual" function, which makes the recursive part private and keeps the global namespace cleaner.

Comment: You can also add something to an array in JS with `nodes[nodes.length] = theItem`

Comment: But declaring the array in the function is going to erase the previous one, no ?

Comment: Yes - that's why I said you should make the array a **parameter** to the function. When you call the function, pass in the array.  A common pattern is to wrap your function in an "outer" function.  I'll update my answer ...